# Implementing pairs on an SECD machine in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to implement pairs on a SECD machine in C, but when I try getting the first element
of a pair, I get the address of the pair instead.

The interpreter accepts as input bytecode defined like, follwing:

```c
#include <stdint.h>

#define HALT    0
#define LDC     1
#define PAIR    12
#define FST     13
```

The basic definitions that can reproduce the problem are

```c
typedef struct _env_node_t {
  value_t elm;
  struct _env_node_t *next;
} env_node_t;

typedef env_node_t *env_t;

typedef intptr_t value_t;
typedef struct {
  int pc;
  env_t env;
} dump_t;

typedef struct pair {
  int fst;
   snd;
} pair_t;
```

The `interp_t` function reads the bytecode (something like [1,4,1,10,12,0]), and
the interacts with the stack:

```c
#include "secd.h" // this is the file that contains the opcode and other definitions
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int code[CODE_MAX];
value_t stack[STACK_MAX];
dump_t dump[DUMP_MAX];

env_t extend(value_t elm, env_t env) {
  env_t nenv = (env_t)malloc(sizeof(env_node_t));
  assert(nenv != NULL);
  nenv->elm = elm;
  nenv->next = env;
  return nenv;
}

value_t lookup(int n, env_t env) {
  while (n > 0) {
    assert(env != NULL);
    env = env->next;
    n--;
  }
  return env->elm;
}


value_t interp(void) {
  int pc = 0;
  int sp = 0;
  int dp = 0;
  env_t env = NULL;

  for (;;) {
    value_t opa, opb;
    int t;
    closure_t *cptr;
    env_t nenv;

    int opcode = code[pc++];

    printf("sp: %d, pc: %d, opcode: %d, dp: %d\n", sp, pc, opcode, dp);

    printf("stack: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < sp; i++) {
      printf("%ld ", stack[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    switch (opcode) {
    case LDC:
      opa = (value_t)code[pc++];
      stack[sp++] = opa;
      break;

    case PAIR:
      opa = stack[--sp];
      opb = stack[--sp];
      pair_t *pair = (pair_t *)malloc(sizeof(pair_t));
      pair->fst = opb;
      pair->snd = opa;
      stack[sp++] = (value_t)pair;
      printf("fst %li, snd %li\n",pair->fst, pair->snd);
      break;

    case FST:
      opa = stack[--sp];
      pair_t *pr = (pair_t *)opa;
      value_t fst = pr->fst;
      printf("fst = %li\n", fst);
      stack[++sp] = fst;
      break;


    case HALT:
      return stack[--sp];

    default:
      fprintf(stderr, "invalid opcode %d at program counter %d\n", opcode, pc);
      exit(-1);
    }
    assert(sp >= 0 && sp < STACK_MAX);
    assert(dp >= 0 && dp < DUMP_MAX);
    assert(pc >= 0 && pc < CODE_MAX);
  }
}

int read_code(FILE *f) {
  int i = 0, data;

  while (!feof(f) && i < CODE_MAX) {
    fscanf(f, "%d\n", &data);
    code[i++] = data;
  }
  return i;
}

int main(void) {
  value_t v;

  read_code(stdin);
  v = interp();
  printf("\nresult is %d\n", (int)v);
  return 0;
}
```

When I try the same input ([1,4,1,10,12,0]), I'm getting

```
sp: 0, pc: 1, opcode: 1, dp: 0
stack: 
dump: 
sp: 1, pc: 3, opcode: 1, dp: 0
stack: 4 
dump: 
sp: 2, pc: 5, opcode: 12, dp: 0
stack: 4 10 
dump: 
fst 4, snd 10
sp: 1, pc: 6, opcode: 13, dp: 0
stack: 94232908375744 
dump: 
fst = 4
sp: 1, pc: 7, opcode: 0, dp: 0
stack: 94232908375744 
dump: 

result is 1325901504
```

Why I can print the fst correctly, but when I try to put it on the stack, it just
returns the address of the pair, instead of the actual value of fst, which is 4?